# Pages become glitchy after opening an folder with apps in app menu

Tags: 20.04, appmenu

i've experencing the issue for a long time, and it annoys me.
the pages in the app menu become glitchy after i open a folder.

### Before Opening an app folder

[image: Before]

### After

[image: After]

How can i fix it?
can provide more info if needed.

**Edit 2**: Tried Ubuntu 20.04.1 on another computer, same bug. Maybe i should report it as a bug?

Comment: What do you mean by 'glitchy'?  Both the screenshots look identical.

Comment: They are not identical. the 2 dots (pages) multiply after opening a folder like an folder with the LibreOffice apps.